# Как сделать двойной свайп для слайдера?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, swiper

Подскажите, есть слайдер на мобилке. Со 100% шириной слайда. И несколько слайдов с 200% ширины.

Использую swiper slider и там если слайд большой, то можно добавить только скролл внутри большого слайда
Была идея сделать большому слайду все таки ширину 100%, но просто изображению внутри дать 200%, и следующему слайду дать отступ слева, но тогда через буллеты некорректно переключает и последний слайд недоступен

Можно ли как то средствами этого слайдера реализовать, что бы один слайд два раза свайпить? Сначала первые 50%, потом другие? Может кто сталкивался с таким

Вот сама страница https://jukachu.github.io/carveli/dist/product-page-eng.html

Только на мобилке

Спасибо

Comment: может просто распилить большую картинку пополам? тогда как раз будет два свайпа

Comment: @2ip вариант хороший
я об этом думал, но заказчик сказал что с этим играть не будет )

Comment: а если поручить это программе? Разрезать картинку пополам, если она в ширину 200%.